# Ubuntu & Netplan - Example of blackhole or unreachable routes

Tags: server, 18.04, routing, router, netplan

I have not found examples of how to configure Netplan in Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 with global blackhole/unreachable routes. So I'll put it here in case someone else runs into the same problem, has an example.

Answer (score 2):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    lo:
      match:
        name: lo
      addresses: [ 127.0.0.2/32 ]
      routes:
        - to: 10.0.0.0/8
          via: 0.0.0.0
          metric: 240
          type: unreachable
        - to: 192.168.0.0/16
          via: 0.0.0.0
          metric: 240
          type: unreachable
        - to: 172.16.0.0/12
          via: 0.0.0.0
          metric: 240
          type: unreachable
        - to: 169.254.0.0/16
          via: 0.0.0.0
          metric: 240
          type: blackhole
```

- Tip: without "address 127.0.0.2" or without "via 0.0.0.0" netplan silently ignores the configuration.